# Conditional formatting in datatable R

Tags: r, datatable, conditional-formatting, dt

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  Rider = c("Rider1", "Rider2", "Rider3", "Rider4", "Rider1", "Rider2", "Rider3", "Rider4"),
  Rider1 = c(10, 20, 15, 25, 30, 45, 30, 43),
  Rider2 = c(12, 22, 14, 24, 32, 30, 56, 75),
  Rider3 = c(9, 19, 11, 21, 29, 40, 20, 19),
  Rider4 = c(11, 21, 13, 23, 31, 29, 40, 20)
)
```

I am making an rmd and would like to display this dataframe as a datatable using the `DT` package in R. I would like to format the table so it looks like this with the values where the rows in the Rider column match the column names are highlighted (change background colour ideally):[image]

I have tried this and a few other options but to no avail.

```
datatable(data) %>%
  formatStyle(
    columns = c("Rider1", "Rider2", "Rider3", "Rider4"),
    valueColumns = "Rider",
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(data$Rider, c("Rider1" = "yellow", "Rider2" = "lightblue", "Rider3" = "lightgreen", "Rider4" = "lightpink"))
  )
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated or even a different table package if `DT` isn't going to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get colour values from additional columns, and use forloop to assign background colours for each column:

```
#matrix with diagonal values set to colours
m <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
diag(m) <- "red"
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
# [1,] "red" NA    NA    NA   
# [2,] NA    "red" NA    NA   
# [3,] NA    NA    "red" NA   
# [4,] NA    NA    NA    "red"

#make dt object hiding colour columns
x <- datatable(cbind(data, rbind(m, m)),
               options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, 
                                                     targets = 7:10))))

#loop through columns and set colour from colour columns 7:10
for(i in 3:6){
  x <- x %>%
    formatStyle(i, valueColumns = i + 4, backgroundColor = JS("value"))
}

x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Works great in that example. I have other situations where I may not always have 8 rows, sometimes 7 and ends with Rider3 and sometimes >8 ending with a different rider - I have a few ideas I will play with, but if you have any solutions that would be great too? Cheers!